# improve query performance in postgres

Tags: postgresql, query-performance, postgresql-performance, postgis, postgresql-13

i have a table addressfabric_v2_2021_12

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.addressfabric_v2_2021_12(
country character varying(10) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
areaname1 character varying(10) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
areaname2 character varying(100) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
areaname3 character varying(100) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
areaname4 character varying(100) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
postcode character varying(20) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
pbkey character varying(50) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
prop_type character varying(10) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
postcode_ext character varying(10) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
add_number character varying(20) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
streetname character varying(60) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
unit_type character varying(20) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
unit_num character varying(50) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
type character varying(3) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
lat character varying(20) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
lon character varying(20) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
parent character varying(50) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
geoid character varying(50) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
geometry geometry,
CONSTRAINT enforce_addfb_srid_geometry_2021_12 CHECK (st_srid(geometry) = 4326))
```

I am having performance issue in the below query

```
 select count(*) from addressfabric_v2_2021_12 as addr, (
SELECT ST_SubDivide('POLYGON((-74.4234467 40.7541435,-74.3904877 40.7489001,-74.380188 40.7587776,-74.3891144 40.7748904,-74.4179535 40.7790479,-74.4316864 40.7665746,-74.4241333 40.7566983,-74.4234467 40.7541435))'::geometry,20)) as
f(geom) where st_intersects(ST_SetSRID(f.geom,4326),addr.geometry);
```

After this i created the following index

```
  CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS addressfabric_v2_2021_12_geometry
ON public.addressfabric_v2_2021_12 USING gist
(geometry)  TABLESPACE pg_default;
```

The performance was increased but still not satisfactory

```
Aggregate  (cost=591866320.40..591866320.41 rows=1 width=8) (actual 
        time=11.812..11.813 rows=1 loops=1)->Nested Loop  (cost=0.55..591346132.52 rows=208075152 width=0) (actual 
               time=0.219..11.476 rows=7072 loops=1)
    ->ProjectSet  (cost=0.00..30.02 rows=1000 width=32) (actual 
                     time=0.010..0.012 rows=1 loops=1)
          ->  Result  (cost=0.00..0.01 rows=1 width=0) (actual 
                       time=0.001..0.001 rows=1 loops=1)
    ->  Index Scan using addressfabric_v2_2021_12_geomtry on 
        addressfabric_v2_2021_12 addr  (cost=0.55..591138.01 rows=20808 
        width=32) (actual time=0.207..10.893 rows=7072 loops=1)
          Index Cond: (geometry && st_setsrid((st_subdivide('01030000000100000008000000580630C0199B52C0D87E32C687604440603F1FC0FD9852C04EBC5EF5DB5F44403A950C00559852C0FC77D89F1F614440C5991540E79852C0FFFDCE9B2F634440EB6F09C0BF9A52C03D4272D7B76344403188FEBFA09B52C0DE78D21D1F6244404029FFFF249B52C02AB8697DDB604440580630C0199B52C0D87E32C687604440'::geometry, 20, '-1'::double precision)), 4326))
          Filter: st_intersects(st_setsrid((st_subdivide('01030000000100000008000000580630C0199B52C0D87E32C687604440603F1FC0FD9852C04EBC5EF5DB5F44403A950C00559852C0FC77D89F1F614440C5991540E79852C0FFFDCE9B2F634440EB6F09C0BF9A52C03D4272D7B76344403188FEBFA09B52C0DE78D21D1F6244404029FFFF249B52C02AB8697DDB604440580630C0199B52C0D87E32C687604440'::geometry, 20, '-1'::double precision)), 4326), geometry)
          Rows Removed by Filter: 1987
Planning Time: 0.685 ms
Execution Time: 11.900 ms
```

Any help will be appreciated.

> EDIT

on rewriting  the query using join , queryplan is including a function scan also

```
  select count(*) from addressfabric_v2_2022_1 as addr join ST_SubDivide('POLYGON((-74.4234467 40.7541435,-74.3904877 40.7489001,-74.380188 40.7587776,-74.3891144 40.7748904,-74.4179535 40.7790479,-74.4316864 40.7665746,-74.4241333 40.7566983,-74.4234467 40.7541435))'::geometry,20)as f(geom) on st_intersects(ST_SetSRID(f.geom,4326),addr.geometry);
```

QUERY PLAN

```
Aggregate  (cost=543972801.24..543972801.25 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=11.208..11.209 rows=1 loops=1)->Nested 
 Loop(cost=25.55..543493555.50 rows=191698296 width=0) 
(actual time=0.114..10.856 rows=7073 loops=1)
->Function Scan on st_subdivide f  (cost=25.00..35.00 rows=1000 
 width=32) (actual time=0.010..0.011 rows=1 loops=1)
->  Index Scan using addressfabric_v2_2022_1_geometry on 
addressfabric_v2_2022_1 addr(cost=0.55..543301.82 rows=19170 
width=32)   (actual time=0.101..10.220 rows=7073 loops=1)
Index Cond: (geometry && st_setsrid(f.geom, 4326))
Filter: st_intersects(st_setsrid(f.geom, 4326), geometry)
Rows Removed by Filter: 1987
Planning Time: 0.092 ms
Execution Time: 11.240 ms
```

Is there any way to create index instead of function scan in new query plan?

update query plan after parallel setting and large dataset

```
Aggregate  (cost=10539438036.82..10539438036.83 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=740.148..740.149 rows=1 loops=1)
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=10000000025.55..10538917273.50 rows=208305328 width=0) (actual time=0.173..717.950 rows=429963 loops=1)
        ->  Function Scan on st_subdivide f  (cost=25.00..35.00 rows=1000 width=32) (actual time=0.008..0.010 rows=1 loops=1)
        ->  Index Scan using addressfabric_v2_2022_1_geometry on addressfabric_v2_2022_1 addr  (cost=0.55..538708.93 rows=20831 width=32) (actual time=0.162..679.372 rows=429963 loops=1)
              Index Cond: (geometry && st_setsrid(f.geom, 4326))
              Filter: st_intersects(st_setsrid(f.geom, 4326), geometry)
              Rows Removed by Filter: 32726
Planning Time: 0.108 ms
Execution Time: 740.184 ms
```

Comment: The JSON execution plan isn't really meant to be read by humans. It's better to post the plan generated using `explain (analyze, buffers format text)`

Comment: I'm afraid the only reason for the performance improvement after the index creation, was an amount of data that was kept in memory, so didn't need disk access.  I can't see how, given a polygon, possible intersecting geometries could be generated to look up using the index.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille  Making that faster is exactly what GiST indexes and postgis extension is for.

Comment: @jjanes Of course, but if you have nothing to search for, what use is an index?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name updated the query plan

Comment: @jjanes updated  as required

Comment: So there was an advantage with the index: reading the entire index avoided reading the entire table.  I stand corrected.

Comment: Are you always searching for that exact polygon, or a limited set of polygons?

Comment: @GerardH.Pille no polygon is not exact and may change.

Comment: Do you have multiple addresses with the same geometry?

Comment: This query accepts custom geographic boundaries and  returns the total number of addresses within these boundaries.

Comment: That is not what I asked. I can see what your query does, but not how many different geometries there are.

Comment: geometry does not have multiple addresses

Comment: 11ms (0.011 s) is pretty darn fast.  What is your goal?

Comment: This is the time of EXPLAIN ANALYZE which is much faster than running the query normally The query takes over a half second. Reference (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3420563/postgres-explain-analyze-is-much-faster-than-running-the-query-normally)

Answer (score 1):

The issue was resolved by changing the following parameters

- `work_mem`  changed from 4mb to 50 mb
- `random_Page_cost` changed to 1 from 4
- `max_wal_size` reduced to 128 mb from 2 gb
- `cpu_index_tuple_cost` to 0.003

Also changed the following as suggested by @Gerad H.pille

```
 max_parallel__Workers_per_Gather 
 max_parallel_maintainence_workers
```

Comment: Yes it was random_page_cost ,thanks

Comment: BTW, have a look if " select count(*) from addressfabric_v2_2021_12 as addr, (
SELECT ST_SetSRID(ST_SubDivide('POLYGON((-74.4234467 40.7541435,-74.3904877 40.7489001,-74.380188 40.7587776,-74.3891144 40.7748904,-74.4179535 40.7790479,-74.4316864 40.7665746,-74.4241333 40.7566983,-74.4234467 40.7541435))'::geometry,20),4326)) as
f(geom) where st_intersects(f.geom,addr.geometry);"  isn't somewhat faster.

Answer (score 0):

The only way that may get you below half a second, seems to be to throw more CPU at it.  Either you get a faster system, or you use more of what you've got, ie. parallelism.  With PostgreSQL 13 you should be safe.

Before your query, execute:

```
SET max_parallel_workers = 8;
SET max_parallel_workers_per_gather = 4;
```

See: [parallel postgis](http://blog.cleverelephant.ca/2019/05/parallel-postgis-4.html)

Comment: I did not see any significant improvement after this, is there any way by making any change in the index or query?

Comment: Can we change the filter condition  Filter: st_intersects(st_setsrid((st_subdivide('01030000000100000008000000580630C0199B52C0D87E32C687604440603F1FC0FD9852C04EBC5EF5DB5F44403A950C00559852C0FC77D89F1F614440C5991540E79852C0FFFDCE9B2F634440EB6F09C0BF9A52C03D4272D7B76344403188FEBFA09B52C0DE78D21D1F6244404029FFFF249B52C02AB8697DDB604440580630C0199B52C0D87E32C687604440'::geometry, 20, '-1'::double precision)), 4326), geometry)

Comment: What is the query plan with parallel workers?  Can you provide info on HW and OS?

Comment: I am connecting aws rds from local system, config of local system is windows 32 gb ram,I rewrite the query using join and it is better now, i am wondering is there any way to create a index scan instead of funciton scan , i have updated the question with the new findings

Comment: If I had known the cloud was involved I wouldn't have bothered.  If the polygon is variable there is no way to create an index scan.

Comment: IS there any way we can use materialized views to get some time optimization?

Comment: I've asked you for the query plan with the parallel workers.

Comment: i have made the setting as described by you, but still there is no parallel execution,
SET max_parallel_workers = 8;
SET max_parallel_workers_per_gather = 4;

Comment: i have updated the new query plan in the question

Comment: It's not using parallel.  Perhaps your dataset is too small and it would take more than 10ms to start up the server processes.  Don't you have a more serious amount of data available?  Check https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/improve-query-performance-with-parallel-queries-in-amazon-rds-for-postgresql-and-amazon-aurora-postgresql-compatible-edition/

Comment: What do you mean by small dataset ? Do you mean content of the table? IF yes, then addressfabric_v2_2021_12  table has a lot of entries.

Comment: Your explains say: 7073  out of some 20000 rows selected by the ST_SetSRID(f.geom,4326).

Comment: 7073 depends on the polygon that is passed, if i change the polygon then this will vary.This count can reduce also depending on the polygon

Comment: Even so, to select the 7000 records of that polygon, PostgreSQL needs 10ms.  Starting extra servers and merging their data afterwards, would probably take more time.

Comment: Regarding your question about the materialized views: you would need a materialized view for each possible polygon that can be requested.

Comment: i ran the query by changing the polygon which was giving count as 4 lakh plus , parallel was not invoked.

Comment: I lack the knowledge of  a lakh.  Please read the documentation on parallel and AWS RDS, to see what is blocking you.

Comment: As requested by you , i used a larger dataset and have updated the query plan in the question

Comment: Parallel scan are only triggered for btree indexes where as i have a gist index. i tried to create a btree index  ,which did triggered the parallel scan but the performance got worse because for postgis gist is the best index

Comment: I had read this: https://blog.cleverelephant.ca/2019/05/parallel-postgis-4.html